# What are examples of types that implement only one of Send and Sync?

Tags: rust

Just to get better understanding of the `Send` and `Sync` traits, are there examples of types that either:

- Implement `Send` and do not implement `Sync`.
- Implement `Sync` and do not implement `Send`.

Comment: [Huon Wilson's article on `Send` and `Sync`](https://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/02/some-notes-on-send-and-sync/) mention's a hypothetical garbage-collected pointer, `Gc<T>`, as something that might be `Sync` but not `Send`, though he doesn't go into detail.

Comment: @JackO'Connor: Here you go ;)

Comment: @MatthieuM Thanks! :)

Answer (score 23):

First of all, it is important to realize that most structs (or enums) are `Send`:

- any struct that does not contain any reference can be `Send + 'static`
- any struct that contain references with a lower-bound lifetime of `'a` can be `Send + 'a`

As a result, you would generally expect any `Sync` `struct` to be `Send` too, because `Send` is such an easy bar to reach (compared to the much harder bar of being `Sync` which requires safe concurrent modification from multiple threads).

---

However, nothing prevents the creator of a type to specifically mark it as not `Send`. For example, let's resuscitate conditions!

The idea of conditions, in Lisp, is that you setup a handler for a given condition (say: `FileNotFound`) and then when deep in the stack this condition is met then your handler is called.

How would you implement this in Rust?

Well, to preserve threads independence, you would use thread-local storage for the condition handlers (see `std::thread_local!`). Each condition would be a *stack* of condition handlers, with either only the top one invoked or an iterative process starting from the top one but reaching down until one succeeds.

But then, how would you set them?

Personally, I'd use RAII! I would bind the condition handler in the thread-local stack and register it in the frame (for example, using an intrusive doubly-linked list as the stack).

This way, when I am done, the condition handler automatically un-registers itself.

Of course, the system has to account for users doing unexpected things (like storing the condition handlers in the heap and not dropping them in the order they were created), and this is why we use a doubly-linked list, so that the handler can un-register itself from the middle of the stack if necessary.

So we have a:

```
struct ConditionHandler<T> {
    handler: T,
    prev: Option<*mut ConditionHandler<T>>,
    next: Option<*mut ConditionHandler<T>>,
}
```

and the "real" handler is passed by the user as `T`.

---

Would this handler be `Sync`?

Possibly, depends how you create it but there is no reason you could not create a handler so that a reference to it could not be shared between multiple threads.

*Note: those threads could not access its `prev`/`next` data members, which are private, and need not be `Sync`.*

Would this handler be `Send`?

Unless specific care is taken, no.

The `prev` and `next` fields are not protected against concurrent accesses, and even worse if the handler were to be dropped while another thread had obtained a reference to it (for example, another handler trying to un-register itself) then this now dangling reference would cause Undefined Behavior.

*Note: the latter issue means that just switching `Option<*mut Handler<T>>` for `AtomicPtr<ConditionHandler<T>>` is not sufficient; see [Common Pitfalls in Writing Lock-Free Algorithms](http://blog.memsql.com/common-pitfalls-in-writing-lock-free-algorithms/) for more details.*

---

And there you have it: a `ConditionHandler<T>` is `Sync` if `T` is `Sync` but will never be `Send` (as is).

For completeness, many types implement `Send` but not `Sync` (most `Send` types, actually): `Option` or `Vec` for example.

Comment: *let's resuscitate conditions!* — you are a crazy, crazy person. I love it.

Comment: What an answer! Bravo! @matthieu-m

Answer (score 16):

[`Cell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) and [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) implement `Send` but not `Sync` because they can be safely sent between threads but not shared between them.

Comment: This isn't correct, AtomicIsize etc. do in fact implement Send. It isn't listed on the doc page because the implementation is autoderived, unlike Sync which must be explicitly derived for them. However, a simple `let v: &Send = &AtomicIsize::new(5);` shows that they implement Send.

Comment: I've edited out the incorrect part that @wingedsubmariner pointed out.

Comment: You can directly check whether types implement the traits ([play example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c9f429c722da91aaf4a450eedaf16e21&version=stable))

Answer (score 0):

For Sync only I guess: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html , it does not look like to have a Send implemented on it.

For Send only you have Cell family.