# This slightly modified Rc<()> is Sync, but not Send, right?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I've searched for types that are `Sync`, but not `Send`, because it often looks like one trait is a superset of the other one (“every type that implements `Sync` also implements `Send`”). I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387421/what-are-examples-of-types-that-implement-only-one-of-send-and-sync), but the only real answer is really complicated.

So I've come up with this code:

```
struct Foo(Rc<()>);  // <-- private field

impl Foo {
    fn my_clone(&mut self) -> Self {  // <-- mutable borrow
        Foo(self.0.clone())
    }
}
```

I know that the compiler won't automatically implement `Send` nor `Sync` for my type; but I'm interested in what I *could* safely implement manually. I think:

- **It should be able to implement `Sync`**: having an *immutable* reference to `Foo` won't let us do anything with it (because we can only call `my_clone()` via mutable/exclusive reference). And without doing anything, nothing can go wrong, right?
- **It should *not* be able to implement `Send`**: we can clone our `Foo` in the main thread (before starting another thread) to get a second object. Now both objects share some memory (the reference count, stored in a `Cell<usize>`). If I now could send one of those objects to another thread, both threads would have ownership of a `Foo`, referencing the same memory. Thus both objects could call `my_clone()` at the same time, leading to simultaneous, unsynchronized, mutable access to the reference count (a data race).

Is this reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that the compiler won't automatically implement `Send` nor `Sync` for my type.

Indeed, the compiler automatically implements `Send` and `Sync` for you, only when it can determine it is safe to do so.

This little program:

```
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicUsize;

fn ensure_sync<T: Sync>(_: T) {}

struct Automatic(AtomicUsize);

impl Automatic {
    fn new() -> Automatic { Automatic(AtomicUsize::new(0)) }
}

fn main() {
    ensure_sync(AtomicUsize::new(0));
    ensure_sync(Automatic::new());
    ensure_sync(Cell::new(0));
}
```

Only errors out on the `Cell::new(0)` line, `Automatic` is `Sync` because all its fields are `Sync`.

---

Regarding `Foo`, `Rc` is neither `Sync` nor `Send`, so indeed the compiler will not implement either for you.

Can `Foo` be `Sync`?

I *believe*<sup>1</sup> so. As long as NO other operation is added to the module that operate on immutable references. Now or in the future.

Can `Foo` be `Send`?

I agree with your conclusion, but I think you missed another method that modifies the `Cell`: `drop`.

So, indeed, you seem to have come up with a type that is `Sync` and not `Send`, by using an underlying type that is `Send` and not `Sync`. It may be my nerd sense, I find it quite amusing :)

<sup>1</sup> *When dealing with `unsafe` code, I am never sure of anything. It's very easy to fool oneself into thinking something is safe, simply because a tiny little detail escaped attention.*