# Why does `Arc<T>` require T to be both `Send` and `Sync` in order to be `Send`/`Sync` itself?

Tags: thread-safety, rust

The [`Arc<T>` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#implementations) says:

```
impl<T> Sync for Arc<T> where T: Send + Sync + ?Sized
impl<T> Send for Arc<T> where T: Send + Sync + ?Sized
```

An `Arc` allows multiple threads to concurrently access the underlying `T` via an immutable reference `&T`. This is safe as long as `T` can't be modified in an unsynchronized manner via `&T`. This is true for all types with '*inherited mutability*' (nearly all types) and false for the ones with unsynchronized '*interior mutability*' (e.g. `RefCell`, ...).

As far as I understand it, the `Send` bound is not required here. For example, I *think* sharing [my artificial type which implements `Sync` but not `Send`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846177/this-slightly-modified-rc-is-sync-but-not-send-right) in an `Arc` is safe.

Lastly, `&T` itself also doesn't have this bound! In the documentation for [`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html) and [`Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html) we find:

```
impl<'a, T> Send for &'a T where T: Sync + ?Sized
impl<'a, T> Sync for &'a T where T: Sync + ?Sized
```

And as `Arc<T>` allows the same access to `T` as `&T` does, I don't understand why `Arc<T>` has the additional `Send` bound. **Why is that?**

Comment: I wonder if this is a remnant from when `Send` implied `static`, since sharing data across threads require `static` in the standard library at the moment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*I believe* this is because an `Arc` *owns* the value it contains, and is thus responsible for dropping it.

Consider the following sequence:

- A value of type `T` is created in thread 1.  It is not `Send`, which means it is *not* safe to move this value to another thread.
- This value is moved into an `Arc` handle.
- A clone of the handle is sent to thread 2.
- The handle stored by thread 1 is dropped.
- The handle stored by thread 2 is dropped.  Since this is the last handle, it assumes full ownership of the stored value and drops it.

And just like that, we've moved a value of type `T` from one thread to another, violating memory safety.

`&T` doesn't require `Send` because dropping a `&T` *never* allows you to drop the underlying value.

**Addendum**: As an example of a type where this would be a problem, consider a type like `struct Handle(usize);` which is backed by a thread-local array of resources.  If the `Drop` implementation for such a type is run on the wrong thread, this will lead to it *either* doing an out-of-bounds access (where it tries to destroy a resource that doesn't exist on this thread), or destroys a resource that's still in use.

Comment: Ahh! Right, thank you! @Matthieu M. even mentioned the hidden access via `drop()` in the other question. So I guess my statement "`Arc<T>` only accesses `T` in the same way `&T` does" is wrong, because `Arc<T>` mutably access `T` for `drop()`. Awesome!

Comment: One thing thought: could you maybe use my `Foo` type from the other question to show that we *could* achieve unsafety? I think a specific example is easier to understand than "a `T` that is not `Send`".

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt I don't think that specific example would be a problem *in practice.*  Off the top of my head, things like handles into thread-local storage, or OS values that must only be used from a specific thread come to mind.  Think something like `struct Handle(usize);` that indexes into a thread-local array of resources; dropping it on the wrong thread would result in either an out-of-bounds access, or deleting the wrong resource.

Comment: Oh, true. My bad, you are right. And you just showed me another example for a type implementing `Sync` but not `Send`. Interesting... thanks!

Comment: I would encourage you to put the `struct Handle(usize);` example in your answer; it exposes succinctly an easy to understand issue that would arise from not requiring the `Send` bound for `impl Send for Arc`. I think this may also indicate why it's required for `Sync`, given the presence of `clone_from` which can do the same with just a reference.

Comment: Also note that ```Arc<T>``` provides a method ```try_unwrap()``` which consumes the ```Arc<T>``` and moves the contained ```T``` out, if the strong ref count is one. That's another way to move ```T``` to another thread.

Comment: If `struct Handle<usize>` can only be accessed by one thread, then it is not `Sync` either. So `Arc<T>` only need to require `T` to be `Sync`.