# Must everything used in thread be `Send`able in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm trying to implement concurrent processing in Rust. Here is the (simplified) code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=44cda381824a4ac4e1524f63dd74378e)):

```
struct Checker {
    unsendable: std::rc::Rc<String> // `Rc` does not implement Send + Sync (`Rc` just for simplicity, a graph actually)
}

impl Checker {
    pub fn check(&self, input: String) -> bool {
        // some logics (no matter)
        true
    }
}

struct ParallelChecker {
    allow_checker: Checker,
    block_checker: Checker
}

impl ParallelChecker {
    // `String` for simplicity here
    pub fn check(&self, input: String) -> bool {
        let thread_pool = rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::new()
            .num_threads(2)
            .build()
            .unwrap();

        // scoped thread pool for simplicity (to avoid `self` is not `'static`)
        thread_pool.scope(move |s| {
            s.spawn(|_| {
                let result = self.allow_checker.check(input.clone());
                // + send result via channel
            });
        });

        thread_pool.scope(move |s| {
            s.spawn(|_| {
                let result = self.block_checker.check(input.clone());
                // + send result via channel
            });
        });

        true // for simplicity
        // + receive result form the channels
    }
}
```

The problem is that `self.allow_checker` and `self.block_checker` don't implement `Send`:

```
55 |         thread_pool.scope(move |s| {
   |                     ^^^^^ `Rc<String>` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `Checker`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `Rc<String>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Checker`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `Mutex<Checker>`
   = note: 1 redundant requirements hidden
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `Arc<Mutex<Checker>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/parallel_checker.rs:55:27: 60:10]`
```

I was under the impression that only **something that is sent via the channels** must implement `Send + Sync` and i'm probably wrong here.

As you can see the threads code does not have any shared variables (except `self`). How can i make it working without implementing `Send` and paying no costs on sync?

I've tried to synchronize the access (though it looks like useless as there is no shared variable in threads), but no luck:

```
    let allow_checker = Arc::new(Mutex::new(self.allow_checker));
        thread_pool.scope(move |s| {
            s.spawn(|_| {
                let result = allow_checker.lock().unwrap().check(input.clone());
                // + send result via channel
            });
        });
```

PS. Migrating to `Arc` is highly undesired due to performance issue and lot's of related code to be migrated to `Arc` too.

Comment: Further reading on `Send` and `Sync`, which may help you understand them better: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28387421/147192

Comment: Could you provide a bit more insight into your use case? Depending on the type of work you're doing, one solution could simply be dereferencing all the `Rc`s before passing them to the thread pool since it's scoped. Though this might also require lots of migration/duplication, and might cause a mess of lifetimes. Also, I would actually benchmark and see if `Arc` is really too slow for your use case, I think it's going to be pretty insignificant compared to the cost of a thread pool! (even at scale)

Comment: @Coder-256 Rc's are used to cache: think of some kind of `builder` design pattern that either builds or returns already existing object for the "input string". How can i benchmark it (as it's just uncompilable without `Arc`?). For now it happens that concurrent version is 3x times slower than single-threaded..

Comment: I'm not sure that the concurrent version really is concurrent: quoting from [rayon's doc](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.0/rayon/fn.scope.html): _When the closure returns, it will block until all tasks that have been spawned into `s` complete._ So you spawn a thread to execute `allow_checker`, wait until it completes, then spawn a thread to execute `block_checker`. You should have a single `scope` in which you spawn both checkers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I was under the impression that only something that is sent via the channels must implement `Send + Sync` and I'm probably wrong here.

You are *slightly* wrong:

- A type is [`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Send.html) if its values can be sent across threads. Many types are `Send`, `String` is, for example.
- A type is [`Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Sync.html) if references to its values can be accessed from multiple threads without incurring any data-race. Perhaps surprisingly this means that `String` is `Sync` -- by virtue of being immutable when shared -- and in general `T` is `Sync` for any `&T` that is `Send`.

Note that those rules do not care *how* values are sent or shared across threads, only that they are.

This is important here because *the closure* you use to start a thread is itself sent across threads: it is created on the "launcher" thread, and executed on the "launched" thread.

As a result, this closure must be `Send`, and this means that anything it captures must in turn be `Send`.

> Why doesn't `Rc` implement `Send`?

Because its reference count is non-atomic.

That is, if you have:

- Thread A: one `Rc`.
- Thread B: one `Rc` (same pointee).

And then Thread A drops its handle at the same time Thread B creates a clone, you'd expect the count to be 2 (still) but due to non-atomic accesses it could be only 1 despite 2 handles still existing:

- Thread A reads count (2).
- Thread B reads count (2).
- Thread B writes incremented count (3).
- Thread A writes decremented count (1).

And then, the next time B drops a handle, the item is destructed and the memory released and any further access via the last handle will blow up in your face.

> I've tried to synchronize the access (though it looks like useless as there is no shared variable in threads), but no luck:

You can't wrap a type to make it `Send`, it doesn't help because it doesn't change the fundamental properties.

The above race condition on `Rc` could happen even with a `Rc` wrapped in `Arc<Mutex<...>>`.

And therefore `!Send` is contagious and "infects" any containing type.

> Migrating to `Arc` is highly undesired due to performance issue and lot's of related code to be migrated to `Arc` too.

`Arc` itself has relatively little performance overhead, so it seems unlikely it would matter unless you keep cloning those `Checker`, which you could probably improve on -- passing references, instead of clones.

The higher overhead here will come from `Mutex` (or `RwLock`) if `Checker` is not `Sync`. As I mentioned, any immutable value is trivially `Sync`, so if you can refactor the internal state of `Checker` to be `Sync`, then you can avoid the `Mutex` entirely and just have `Checker` contain `Arc<State>`.

If you have mutable state at the moment, consider extracting it, going towards:

```rust
struct Checker {
    unsendable: Arc<Immutable>,
}

impl Checker {
    pub fn check(&self, input: String) -> Mutable {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Or drop the idea of parallel checks.

Comment: @Jmb: The `Mutex` will prevent the race-condition _on the `Rc` wrapped in the `Mutex`_, but what about all it clones on either threads? (1) Thread A can have clones from before the wrapping, (2) Thread B can trivially produce clones `arc_mutex.lock().unwrap().clone()` and those clones are not guarded.

Comment: Is there any opportunity to avoid infecting all the structs used instead of `unsendable` in the example using `Arc` every here and there?

Comment: @4ntoine: For something to be `Send`, it needs to recursively contain only `Send` types. For more specific advice, we'd need to see a more precise picture of the innards of `Checker` instead of the dummy you made for the MCVE.

Answer (score 2):

The requirement for `Send` is not limited to channels. If you look at the documentation for [`thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html), you will see that the closure it takes must be `Send`, and therefore can only capture `Send` values. The same applies to the closure taken by [`rayon::ThreadPool::scope`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.0/rayon/struct.ThreadPool.html#method.scope).

Since you're cloning the strings in the closures, you might as well clone them before spawning the threads:

```
let input_clone = input.clone();
thread_pool.scope(move |s| {
    s.spawn(|_| {
        let result = self.allow_checker.check(input_clone);
        // + send result via channel
    });
});
```

Comment: the problem is not with `String` or `&str`, but with `self.allow_checker` which has a member that does not implement `Send` and `Sync`

Comment: Sorry, I read the code too quickly. Then you can't avoid `Arc`. Matthieu M.'s answer shows why you can't have an `Rc` accessed from more than one thread. Have you _measured_ the performance cost of `Arc`?