# Is the Sync trait a strict subset of the Send trait; what implements Sync without Send?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, traits

In [*"Programming Rust, 2nd Edition"* by Jim Blandy, Jason Orendorff, Leonora F.S. Tindall](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-rust-2nd/9781492052586/)
 on page 520 there is a graph that shows Send and Sync with overlapping circles with Sync totally subsumed by Send.

[image: Figure 19-9. Send and Sync types]

This leads me to believe that everything that implements Sync must also implement Send, but this example from page 561 and everything I've seen always specifies them both seperately,

```rust
type GenericError = Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static>
```

Why if 100% of things that implement Sync are also Send, is Sync not a subtrait of Send? Why trait bounds need to specify both? Why do people mark both. Is there any usecase of something to be Sync and **not** Send? In what case, can you share a mutable reference with another thread, but not grant ownership to that other thread?

Comment: I believe this is, ultimately, a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387421/what-are-examples-of-types-that-implement-only-one-of-send-and-sync/. I'll wait for confirmation, though, since my dupe votes are golden...

Comment: Yeah, this is wrong, my mistake. We'll have to fix that in the next edition of the book. Thanks for asking about this, and thanks to Alice and Aplet123 for answering.

Comment: @JasonOrendorff : 
It would be nice of you, a year after acknowledging the mistake, to explain it here, and no one should have to wait for the new edition of the book (especially if, like me, they purchased the previous edition). Nevertheless, it remains "a great book." Thank you.

Comment: @openyourmind Hi! I'm glad you liked the book despite the error. Please let me know what I should clear up here. The diagram is wrong: Sync-but-not-Send types exist. There are already two good explanations of the error on this page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When a type implements the `Send` trait, that allows you to perform the following actions:

1. Mutably access the value from threads other than the one it was created on. This includes dropping it.
2. Immutably access the value from threads other than the one it was created from. (But not necessarily in parallel.)

When a type implements the `Sync` trait, that allows you to perform the following actions:

1. Immutably access the value from several threads in parallel.

Another way to "define" the meaning of `T: Sync` is simply as whether it would be safe for `&T` to be `Send`. This makes sense because an `&T` can be copied, so making copies and sending them to different threads would allow parallel immutable access.

---

If a value is `Send + !Sync`, then it may be accessed in any way from any thread, but only from one thread at the time, even if the access is immutable.

If a value is `!Send + Sync`, then it may be accessed immutably from any thread, and from several threads in parallel. However, mutable access must happen on the thread it was created on.

---

Some examples:

- [`MutexGuard`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html) - destroying a `MutexGuard` on another thread is unsound, so it can't be `Send`. However if the value inside may be immutably accessed from several threads in parallel, then such an immutable access would also be safe on the `MutexGuard` itself.
- [`SyncWrapper`](https://docs.rs/sync_wrapper/) - an immutable reference to a `SyncWrapper<T>` does not allow you to perform any actions at all, so it is always safe for it to be `Sync`. (The linked crate requires the inner value to be `Send`, but this is stricter than necessary)
- [`&T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.reference.html) - since immutable references can be copied, the ability to send one to another thread would let you perform immutable access from several threads in parallel. Thus `&T` can only be `Send` if `T` is `Sync`. There is no need for `T` to be `Send` as an `&T` doesn't allow mutable access.
- [`&mut T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.reference.html) - mutable references can't be copied, so sending them to other threads doesn't allow access from several threads in parallel, thus `&mut T` can be `Send` even if `T` is not `Sync`. Of course, `T` must still be `Send`.
- [`Arc<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) - this mostly behaves like `&T`. It can be cloned, so sending it to other threads requires `T: Sync`. However, it *also* requires `T: Send` as the last `Arc<T>` might be dropped on a different thread than where `T` was created, which you can't do without `Send`.
- [`RefCell<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) - this type can never be `Sync` because you can modify the value inside with only an immutable reference, and this would be a data race if you could do it from several threads in parallel. There's no problem with `RefCell<T>` being `Send` provided that `T` is.
- [`Rc<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) - if you have two clones of the same `Rc<T>`, then it would be a data race to access them from different threads in parallel. This rules out both `Send` and `Sync`, since both of them would allow immutable access from other threads, and that other thread could use that to call `.clone()` remotely and obtain an `Rc<T>` on the other thread.

Comment: Generally I like the form of this answer, I wish you would include/address this from the other upvoted answer _The only relationship between Send and Sync is that T is Sync if and only if &T is Send (it makes sense since "syncing" across threads is really just being able to share a reference to it across threads)._ I think that's important, but generally I think this is exemplary. For example, if I mark `&T` as `Send`, is `T` automagically Sync?

Comment: I added a few more examples, including the reference types as requested. Generally, the compiler is unable to deduce that `T` must be `Sync` if `&T` is `Send` (see [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c076787d4b0daa846104c2aa8d442891)), but this is just a limitation in the trait resolver, and the `T: Send` <-> `&T: Sync` relationship does go both ways in the sense that there are no counterexamples.

Comment: Currently learning Rust. I've read multiple sources, including the docs, for the Send & Sync traits. This answer is definitely up there as being the most understandable explanation of the two.

Answer (score 12):

The book appears to be wrong. The only relationship between `Send` and `Sync` is that `T` is `Sync` if and only if `&T` is `Send` (it makes sense since "syncing" across threads is really just being able to share a reference to it across threads). In fact, there's even a type in the standard library which is `Sync` but not `Send`: [`MutexGuard`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html). The reasoning is that the underlying implementation results in undefined behavior when trying to unlock a mutex from a thread other than the thread that locked it.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to have a structure that implements `Sync` but not `Send`:

```rust
struct Foo(*const ());
unsafe impl Sync for Foo {}

fn main() {
    // Note: static just for demo using standard library threads.
    // Can use borrowed thread libraries with this too, where the lifetime isn't static.
    let static_foo_ref = Box::leak(Box::new(Foo(std::ptr::null()))) as &'static Foo;
    
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("Borrow thread, foo ptr: {:?}", static_foo_ref.0);
    }).join().unwrap();
    
    // Doesn't work
    /*let foo_owned = Foo(std::ptr::null());
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("Owned thread, foo ptr: {:?}", foo_owned.0);
    }).join().unwrap();*/
}
```